# How to return range or location of cursor in TinyMCE when clicked or cursor location changed?

Tags: tinymce, onfocus

how can I get the location of the cursor when the TinyMCE editor is focused on or when cursor location changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tinymce [onActivate event](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onActivate) in case of focus.
A cursor location change is possible, but it is expensive to detect, because you will have to check on each key-action if the cursor is still on the previous spot or not.